# Week 4 issue with Cabal build: Not in scope: type constructor or class 'JWT.EncodeSigner'

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal, build

When running `cabal build` or `cabal repl` in the core/week04 folder I get the following error message when building the playground-common-0.1.0.0 package:

```
src/Auth.hs:130:41: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class 'JWT.EncodeSigner'
    Module 'Web.JWT' does not export 'EncodeSigner'
    |
130 |         { _configJWTSignature       :: !JWT.EncodeSigner
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am in the correct branch in the plutus-apps repo as per the cabl.project file in code/week04. I've run cabal update and it was successful.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you run `cabal` from `nix-shell`?

Comment: yes, I do. It appears the issue was that I ran nix-shell under an old commit (for week 3) and restarting the shell _after_ the commit was changed allowed cabal build to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to do a git pull for both 'plutus-master' and 'plutus-pioneer-program'.
Then set the right git-checkout tag (of the week's cabal project file)
Restart nix-shell so it builds the 'plutus-master', after that you can do the following to resolve missing dependencies in the 'week' folder:

- cabal clean
- cabal update
- cabal build
- cabal repl

This should work

Comment: Thanks, the key here for me was to restart the nix-shell. Once I did this everything flowed as expected.